# lightbox2 position vertical

Tags: position, lightbox2

I'm using the lightbox 2 and i'd like to know if it's possible to use something other than "positionFromTop" because I'd like my images to be vertically centered on any screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no build in solution. Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/172